# Edit another Windows install's registry

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry

I have a hard drive plugged into my computer here which I'd like to edit the registry for. When opening up "regedit," it obviously loads the local Windows registry. Is there a way to load the Windows registry for, say, drive G? Is there a certain file I need to open to edit this other installation's registry?

I specifically need to edit a key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\` on the other machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool for edit the windows registry file, system.dat](http://superuser.com/questions/66432/tool-for-edit-the-windows-registry-file-system-dat)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have only done it a few times.
It is a very strange operation to drop in a hive into the registry and edit it, using the quick method, but it worked.
[image]
You select HKLM in your current registry, and then the **File/Load Hive** operation will become usable.
File means you have to find the registry hive file itself by browsing.    `Windows\System32\config`
Load in and name this "other" hive section which will look like it has become part of your current registry.   Use a really obvious and different name, so you can find it.

The strange thing was why I would want to view this all mixed into my current registry, but thats what they said to do ??  There must be a better way to clear the slate and load in ONLY the one hive I want to edit, but it worked, so I rolled with it. I had a full backup, so that helped when presented with this odd method.
Whatever you do certannly do not Import it in, that would be a mess.

Make your changes, which should change it immediatly, Then unload the hive **File/Unload Hive**  and then close.  Selecting unload hive unloads the one you loaded (there are no options then).

more info http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732157.aspx although a good tutorial with pictures is what I used the first time.

Comment: This works just fine, thanks. I had to do this for a mounted VHD associated with a Azure VM which I lost control by changing the default RDP port (in Windows registry settings).

Comment: this shit diesn't work. I tried opening a Win 7 registry using windows 10's regedit like described above, it doesn't show most of the keys.

Answer (score 2):

Any changes you ant to make for the other installation you may need to go to (C:\Users\Himanshu\AppData\Roaming) where "C" is the drive of windows installation and you need to find this file "hkey_local_machine.reg" . When you have got the file make any changes you want to and then load this file into the machine of which the file was taken from.