# Where does windows store network drive mappings?

Tags: windows-7, network-drive

I am not able to boot my windows 7, but I have access to the drive on which Windows 7 is installed.

Is there anyway I can restore my network drives?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Where does windows store network drive mappings?

> When we map a network drive persistently in windows 7 an entry
>   relating to the drive is created under the following key in registry:
>
> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network`
>
> For each drive a key with the name as that of the drive letter is
>   created. For example if you mapped a network drive with letter `W` the
>   key will be `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network\W`
>
> The key will contain the following values:
>
> [image]

Source [Mapped network drives in Windows 7 Registry](http://sysadminslibrary.blogspot.nl/2013/02/mapped-network-drives-in-windows-7.html)

---

#### How do I load the registry from a different Windows Installation?

See this question [Edit another Windows install's registry](https://superuser.com/questions/690982/edit-another-windows-installs-registry) for instructions on how to load the registry for a different windows installation, for example when you have a non-bootable drive.

---

#### What about the credentials (Domain, username, Password)? Where do I find them?

[Network Password Recovery](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_password_recovery.html) from [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) can be used to recover network credentials, even from another external drive (eg from a dead system that cannot boot anymore).

> This utility recovers all network passwords stored on your system for
>   the current logged-on user. It can also recover the passwords stored
>   in Credentials file of external drive, as long as you know the last
>   log-on password.
>
> [image]

...

> **Where the network passwords are stored?**
>
> Older versions of Windows (Windows 95,98 and ME) stored the network
>   passwords in pwl files located under the main Windows folder.
>
> Starting from Windows XP, the network passwords are encrypted inside
>   the Credentials file, located under:
>
> `"Documents and Settings\<User Name>\Application Data\Microsoft\Credentials\<User SID>"`.
>
> Some passwords may also be stored in the Credentials file under:
>
> `"Documents and Settings\<User Name>\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Credentials\<User SID>"`.
>
> In addition to the passwords of network shares, Windows XP also stores
>   the passwords of .NET Passport (MSN Messenger) in the same Credentials
>   files
>
> **Credentials file in external drive**
>
> Starting from version 1.20, you can also read the Credentials from an
>   external profile in your current operating system or from another
>   external drive (For example: from a dead system that cannot boot
>   anymore).
>
> In order to use this feature, you must know the last logged-on
>   password used for this profile, because the Credentials file is
>   encrypted with the SHA hash of the log-on password, and without that
>   hash, the Credentials file cannot be decrypted.
>
> You can use this feature from the UI, by selecting the 'Advanced
>   Options' in the File menu, or from command-line, by using /external
>   parameter.
>
> The user profile path should be something like `"C:\Documents and Settings\admin"` in Windows XP/2003 or `"C:\users\myuser"` in Windows
>   Vista/2008.

Source [Network Password Recovery v1.34 - Recover Windows XP/Vista network passwords (Credentials file)](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_password_recovery.html)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.

Comment: What's about the credentials(Domain, username, Password)? where to find them?

Comment: @MahmoudKhateeb See updated answer